# Refactor a functional component with React hooks

Tags: reactjs

I have several functional components which share the same logic. So I would like to refactor them using React hooks. All of them make some calls to the server on mount to check if the order has been paid. If yes, `paid` state is set to true , and a file is being downloaded. On submit I check if `paid` state is set to true, if yes, the same file is being downloaded, if not, a new order is created and a user is being redirected to a page with a payment form.

I have already extracted all functions (`getOrder()`, `getPaymentState()`, `createOrder()`, `initPayment()` and `downloadFile()`) which make API calls to the server. How can I further optimize this code, so that I could move `checkOrder()`, `checkPayment()`, `downloadPDF()` and `newOrder()` outside the component to use the same logic with other components as well?

Here is my component:

```
const Form = () => {
  const [paid, setPaid] = useState(false);
  const [submitting, setSubmitting] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState({});

  const checkOrder = async () => {
    let search = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    let success = search.get("Success");
    if (success) {
      try {
        const data = await getOrder();
        setData(data);
        checkPayment(data);
      } catch (err) {
        alert(err.message)
      }
    }
  };

  const checkPayment = async values => {
    try {
      const paid = await getPaymentState();
      setPaid(paid);
      downloadPDF(values);
    } catch (err) {
      alert(err.message)
    }
  };

  const downloadPDF = async values => {
    setLoading(true);
    let downloadData = {
      email: values.email,
      phone: values.phone
    }
    const response = await downloadFile(downloadData, sendURL);
    setLoading(false);
    window.location.assign(response.pdf);
  }

  const newOrder = async values => {
    setSubmitting(true);
    const order = await createOrder(values, description, sum);
    const paymentUrl = await initPayment(order, description, sum, returnURL);
    setSubmitting(false);
    window.location.assign(paymentUrl);
  }

  const onSubmit = async values => {
    if (paid) {
      try {
        downloadPDF(data);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    } else {
      try {
        newOrder(values)
      } catch (err) {
        alert(err.message)
      }
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    checkOrder();
  }, []);
  return (

  )
}
```

**EDIT 1**: I also need to be able to pass some data to this hook: `downloadData`, `sendURL`, `description`, `sum` and `returnURL`, which will be different in each case. `downloadData` then needs to be populated with some data from the `values`.

I would appreciate if you could point me at the right direction. I'm just learning React and I would really like to find the correct way to do this.

**EDIT 2**: I've posted my [own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61309518/3354729) with the working code based on the previous answers. It's not final, because I still need to move `downloadPDF()` outside the component and pass `downloadData` to it, but when I do so, I get an error, that values are undefined. If anybody can help me with that, I will accept it as an answer.

Comment: What is it? Is it a custom hook or a component?

Comment: You are not passing any values to getOrder, how does getOrder know what order status to get?

Comment: @DennisVash `Form` is a component

Comment: @HMR `getOrder` performs `new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)` and gets the order number from there. When the payment is made the URL looks like this `?Success=true&PaymentId=&OrderId=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answers above I came up with the following code.

The hook:

```
const useCheckPayment = ({initialValues, sendUrl, successUrl, description, sum, downloadPDF}) => {
  const [paid, setPaid] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [submitting, setSubmitting] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState(initialValues);

  const checkOrder = useCallback(
    async () => {
      let search = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
      let success = search.get('Success');
      if (success) {
        try {
          const data = await getOrder(search);
          setData(data);
          checkPayment(search);
        } catch (err) {
          alert(err.message);
        }
      }
    }, [checkPayment]
  );

  const checkPayment = useCallback(
    async (search) => {
      try {
        const paid = await getPaymentState(search);
        setPaid(paid);
        document.getElementById('myForm').dispatchEvent(new Event('submit', { cancelable: true }))
      } catch (err) {
        alert(err.message);
      }
    }, []
  );

  const newOrder = useCallback(
    async (values) => {
      setSubmitting(true);
      const order = await createOrder(values, description, sum);
      const paymentUrl = await initPayment(order, description, sum, successUrl);
      setSubmitting(false);
      window.location.assign(paymentUrl);
    }, [description, sum, successUrl]
  );

  const downloadPDF = async (values, downloadData) => {
    setLoading(true);
    const response = await downloadFile(downloadData, sendUrl);
    setLoading(false);
    window.location.assign(response.pdf);
  };

  const onSubmit = useCallback(
    async ({ values, downloadData }) => {
      if (paid) {
        try {
          downloadPDF(values, downloadData);
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      } else {
        try {
          newOrder(values);
        } catch (err) {
          alert(err.message);
        }
      }
    },
    [paid, downloadPDF, newOrder]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    checkOrder();
  }, [checkOrder]);

  return { onSubmit, submitting };
};
```

The component:

```
const sendUrl = 'https://app.example.com/send'
const successUrl = 'https://example.com/success'
const description = 'Download PDF file'
const sum = '100'

const Form = () => {

  const handleSubmit = (values) => {
    const downloadData = {
      email: values.email,
      phone: values.phone
    }
    onSubmit({ downloadData, values })
  }

  const { onSubmit, submitting } = useCheckPayment(
    {sendUrl, successUrl, description, sum}
  );

  return (
    <Form
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      render={({ handleSubmit }) => (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}></form>
      )}
    />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I made a quick refactor of the code and put it in a custom hook, it looks like search param is the key for when the effect needs to run.

```
const useCheckPayment = (search) => {
  const [paid, setPaid] = useState(false);
  const [submitting, setSubmitting] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState({});

  const checkOrder = useCallback(async () => {
    let paramSearch = new URLSearchParams(search);
    let success = paramSearch.get('Success');
    if (success) {
      try {
        //why not just pass it, makes getOrder a little less impure
        const data = await getOrder(paramSearch);
        setData(data);
        checkPayment(data);
      } catch (err) {
        alert(err.message);
      }
    }
  }, [checkPayment, search]);

  const checkPayment = useCallback(async (values) => {
    try {
      const paid = await getPaymentState();
      setPaid(paid);
      downloadPDF(values);
    } catch (err) {
      alert(err.message);
    }
  }, []);

  const downloadPDF = async (values) => {
    setLoading(true);
    const response = await downloadFile();
    setLoading(false);
    window.location.assign(response.pdf);
  };

  const newOrder = async (values) => {
    setSubmitting(true);
    const order = await createOrder();
    const paymentUrl = await initPayment(order);
    setSubmitting(false);
    window.location.assign(paymentUrl);
  };
  const onSubmit = useCallback(
    async (values) => {
      if (paid) {
        try {
          downloadPDF(data);
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      } else {
        try {
          newOrder(values);
        } catch (err) {
          alert(err.message);
        }
      }
    },
    [data, paid]
  );
  useEffect(() => {
    checkOrder();
  }, [checkOrder]); //checkOrder will change when search changes and effect is called again
  return { onSubmit, submitting, loading };
};


const Form = () => {
  const { onSubmit, submitting, loading } = useCheckPayment(
    window.location.search
  );

  return '';
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try this. Could you please explain, why you use useCallback in some places? What is it needed for?

Comment: @jupiteror If you use [exhaustive deps](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14920) (I think it's part of create-react-app) then it would tell you your effect has missing dependency `checkOrder` so not wrapping checkOrder in [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) will cause the effect to run on every render because checkOrder is re created every render. With the useCallback checkOrder is created when `checkPayment` or `search` changes so checkPayment is also wrapped in useCallback and will not be re created until component remounts (empty dependency).

Comment: Ok, thank you very much! I have one more question, if I need to pass some parameters to `createOrder()` like sum and description of the order, how can I do that? Add some const to `useCheckPayment()`?

Comment: @jupiteror You can pass them from component to onSubmit.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but `downloadPDF()` is also called without onSubmit. I have edited my question and added params that I need to pass (downloadData, sendURL, description, sum, returnURL). You can find it here https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61236741/revisions. Could you please take a look at it one more time and update your answer?

Comment: I have started a bounty for this question. I would really appreciate if you update your answer. Please see EDIT in my question for details.

Comment: @jupiteror Why not return every function you need to call with arguments: `return { onSubmit, submitting, loading, downloadPDF, any, other, stuff, you, want, to, call, in, your, component }; `

Comment: I didn't quite understand, what you mean. I guess I need to pass these data to the hook and not return it from there. For example, in here `const response = await downloadFile(downloadData, sendURL);` the structure of the `downloadData` and `sendURL` will be different in different components, where the hook will be used. So I need to pass these data to the hook, when it is called in the component.

Comment: @jupiteror `const downloadPDF = async (values, downloadData) => ... ` and `const onSubmit = async (values, downloadData) => ...` or you can pass it to the hook: `const useCheckPayment = (search, downloadData) => ...` but be careful you don't pass a new object every render like `const {what, I need} = useCheckPayment(search,{new:'object',every:'render'})`

Comment: I'm using react-final-form, so onSubmit I can pass only form values. All other things I'm passing when calling the hook `useCheckPayment({sendUrl, successUrl, description, sum});`. But I can't pass downloadData there as well, as it relies on values. So when I define it in my component like this `const downloadData = {email: values.email, phone: values.phone}` and then pass it to `useCheckPayment({downloadData , sendUrl, successUrl, description, sum})`, I get an error that values are not defined.

Answer (score 2):

You can extract out all the generic things from within the Form component into a custom Hook and return the required values from this hook

The values which are dependencies and will vary according to the component this is being called from can be passed as arguments to the hook. Also the hook can return a onSubmit function to which you can pass on the downloadData

```
const useOrderHook = ({returnURL, sendURL, }) => {
  const [paid, setPaid] = useState(false);
  const [submitting, setSubmitting] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState({});

  const checkOrder = async () => {
    let search = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    let success = search.get("Success");
    if (success) {
      try {
        const data = await getOrder();
        setData(data);
        checkPayment(data);
      } catch (err) {
        alert(err.message)
      }
    }
  };

  const checkPayment = async values => {
    try {
      const paid = await getPaymentState();
      setPaid(paid);
      downloadPDF(values);
    } catch (err) {
      alert(err.message)
    }
  };

  const downloadPDF = async values => {
    setLoading(true);
    let downloadData = {
      email: values.email,
      phone: values.phone
    }
    const response = await downloadFile(downloadData, sendURL);
    setLoading(false);
    window.location.assign(response.pdf);
  }

  const newOrder = async (values, description, sum) => {
    setSubmitting(true);
    const order = await createOrder(values, description, sum);
    const paymentUrl = await initPayment(order, description, sum, returnURL);
    setSubmitting(false);
    window.location.assign(paymentUrl);
  }

  const onSubmit = async ({values, downloadData: data, description, sum}) => {
    if (paid) {
      try {
        downloadPDF(data);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    } else {
      try {
        newOrder(values, description, sum)
      } catch (err) {
        alert(err.message)
      }
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    checkOrder();
  }, []);

  return {onSubmit, loading, submitting, paid, data };
}
```

Now you can use this hook in component like Form as follows

```
const Form = () => {
    const {onSubmit, newOrder, loading, submitting, paid, data } = useOrderHook({returnUrl: 'someUrl', sendURL: 'Some send URL'})

    const handleSubmit = (values) => {
        // since this function is called, you can get the values from its closure.
        const data = {email: values.email, phone: values.phone}
        onSubmit({ data, values, description, sum})// pass in the required values for onSubmit here. you can do the same when you actually call newOrder from somewhere
    }
    // this is how you pass on handleSubmit to React-final-form
    return <Form
      onSubmit={handleSubmit }
      render={({ handleSubmit }) => {
        return <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>...fields go here...</form>
      }}
    />
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The only problem is with `downloadData`. I'm using react-final-form, so onSubmit I can pass only form values. All other things I'm passing when calling the hook `useCheckPayment({sendUrl, successUrl, description, sum});`. But I can't pass downloadData there as well, as it relies on values. So when I define it in my component like this `const downloadData = {email: values.email, phone: values.phone}` and then pass it to `useCheckPayment()`, I get an error that values are not defined.

Comment: Could you share how you use onSubmit with react-final-form. Maybe we can work around it

Comment: It's the same as described here https://final-form.org/docs/react-final-form/api/Form#3-do-something-with-handlesubmit. I have `onSubmit={onSubmit}` on the `<Form/>
` from react-final-form, then I have `onSubmit={handleSubmit}` on the html `<form>` element. And then I define `type="submit"` for the button. `onSubmit` is my `onSubmit` function, which is returned from the hook. `handleSubmit` is passed by react-final-form to the render function

Comment: I updated my answer to give you more info about what you could do

Comment: I still get an error that values are undefined. I have posted my own answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61309518/3354729, you can see my recent code there. I had to leave `downloadPDF()` inside the component for it to work. But I would like to move it to the hook and pass `downloadData` to it from the component. (So that the function doesn't have this declaration `let downloadData = {}` and gets these data from the component instead.)

Comment: Did you check my updated answer wherein I added the info about how you could pass on the data to the function in hook

Comment: Yes, I've tried it, but I still get an error that values are undefined. I need to be able to define the downloadData separately from the hook like this `const downloadData = {email: values.email, phone: values.phone}` and then pass it to the hook.

Comment: Please check this function implementation: ```const handleSubmit = (values) => {
            // since this function is called, you can get the values from its closure.
            const data = {email: values.email, phone: values.phone}
            onSubmit({ data, values, description, sum})// pass in the required values for onSubmit here. you can do the same when you actually call newOrder from somewhere
        }``` in the answer

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Now `downloadPDF()` is working from `onSubmit()`, but it's not working from `checkPayment()`, where PDF file should be downloaded automatically on page load, without onSubmit button. I tried to pass `downloadData` there as well, but I get an undefined value instead of an object, as it's passed from the component only on submit.

Comment: I have finally figured it out. Instead of calling `downloadPDF()` from `checkPayment()` directly, I submit form programmatically, so that the values are passed to `downloadPDF()` on submit. Now it works. Thank you 